Postman - Variable declared inside a parent folder, not seen as defined in child folder
I have this test in JavaScript in the Tests tab of the Parent folder (I will have the same 401 test in multiple child folders - to reduce duplications in test)
const response = pm.response.json();

pm.test("Status code is 401", ()=> {
    pm.response.to.have.status(401);
});


In the Child folder, I am trying to post a POST request, while having this test in the Tests tab:
pm.test('Error message', () => {
 pm.expect(response.error).to.eql('Missing Authorization header.');
})

I'm getting:
PASS
Status code is 401
FAIL
Error message | ReferenceError: response is not defined |

I understand that the 2nd test (the one in the child folder) is failing because the variable response is not defined in the Child folder.
My question is: why is the variable not passed from the Parent folder to the Child folder? As I can see, the 401 function is being passed, but the variable is not. I know the solution, I just do not understand the logic behind the variable not being passed, but the function is passed.
Setting the variable as a global variable in the parent folder script and then accessing the global variable in the child folder script works and is fully understood. What I do not understand is why, in my example, the function for testing the 401 status is being passed from the Parent folder to the Child folder, but not the variable response

This will be a scope issue.
When you define the variable using const or let, it will be a type of local variable.
This type of local variable will only be available to the scripting engine that executes it and can persist through a collection run.
For example.  If you define a local variable in the pre-request script for a request, you'll find you can't use it in the tests tab within the same request as that is executed separately.  The same will apply if the script runs from a folder.
This is the behaviour you are seeing.
However.  If you loop through the same request, you will be able to update it and keep referencing it in the pre-request script.
This is how I control sendRequest() loops.  You'll see examples on the Internet where you keep saving an array that is used to control the loop as a collection variable, but its actually not needed.
There is another type of local variable that you set using pm.variables, which will persist between the tabs, the same as your workaround of using pm.globals.
You will however need to use pm.variables.get to retrieve that variable.  You can't just reference it by its name.
